# How to get all the mentions from an user in a channel discord.js

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

So, I'm trying to create a simple bot that when the user writes:

`!howmanypoints {user}`

It should just go to a specific channel, and search how many times it was mentioned in the specific channel.

As of now, I encountered the function fetchMentions() but it seems deprecated and the API doesn't like it when a bot tries to do this..

Any input or at least a better approach for this. Maybe I'm fixated with making it work.

```html
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()


client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.includes('!howmanypoints') ||      msg.content.includes('!cuantospuntos')) {

    const canal_de_share = client.channels.find('name', 'dev')
    const id_user = client.user.id
    client.user.fetchMentions({guild: id_user })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ClientUser.fetchMentions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=fetchMentions) is deprecated, and only available for user accounts.

As an alternative, you could fetch all the messages of the channel and iterate over each, checking for mentions.

Example:

```js
let mentions = 0;

const channel = client.channels.find(c => c.name === 'dev');
const userID = client.user.id;

channel.fetchMessages()
  .then(messages => {
    for (let message of messages) {
      if (message.mentions.users.get(userID)) mentions++;
    }

    console.log(mentions);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hey, I edited your answer, but since it's completely based off your code, I think it would be useful to reflect a "working code".

Comment: from this:

if (mensaje.mentions.users.get(client.user.id))

to this:

if (message[1].content.includes(id_user))

Not really sure why it wasn't working, but I did a workaround.. what do you think?

Comment: You should stick to using [`Message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) for this purpose. If you're searching for *just* the ID of a user in a message, you can split the message into an array of arguments and iterate through them, comparing each to the ID.